# Get n-th result returned from MATCH query in Neo4J database

Tags: sorting, neo4j, cypher, match

I've set up a library database where users borrow books. Using a MATCH Command i can return the book titles and number of their lendings by descending order.

My Cypher for returning the list of books and number of lendings is:

```
MATCH (user)-[:LENDING]->(b:Book)
RETURN b.title, COUNT(b.title) as numberOfRents
ORDER BY numberOfRents DESC
```

This is working properly. However, i need to get the n-th book(by lendings) returned only(let's say the third for example), which is something i failed to do until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [SKIP](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/skip/#query-skip) and [LIMIT](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/limit/#query-limit)

```
MATCH (user)-[:LENDING]->(b:Book)
RETURN b.title, COUNT(b.title) as numberOfRents
ORDER BY numberOfRents DESC
SKIP 2 LIMIT 1
// skips the first 2, so you only get the 3rd
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!